# Universal rendering for react app based on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, universal, isomorphic-javascript

I have an app based on the create-react-app starter kit and need to switch to universal/server rendering due to SEO issues.

Is there an easy way or example of taking the create-react-app teamplate and adding or modifying it to support universal rendering?

A lot of the examples I see for universal are overly complex for my needs and I prefer to keep it very clean and simple, if possible.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** FYI,
I found [this](https://medium.com/@justinjung04/react-server-side-rendering-and-hot-reloading-ffb87ca81a89#.qwtklszfl) medium post which points at [this](https://github.com/justinjung04/universal-boilerplate) repository.

Seems simple enough, but since I'm a newbie on all webpack/react/node related stuff, if anyone thinks it's the wrong approach, would love to know...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a proof of concept of adding server rendering in [this PR](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/172).
I can’t speak to how good it is but it’s something you could start with.

You may also look at some of the [alternatives](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#alternatives).
A few of them provide server rendering out of the box.

Comment: Will do. Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

I've just created react universal (server-side rendering) starter used recommendations from redux and react-router v4. Fill free for feedback

https://github.com/gzoreslav/react-redux-saga-universal-application

Answer (score 0):

You can take your app (bootstrapped with Create React App) to the next level by replacing `react-scripts` with a slightly altered version - `react-app-tools`, which allows adding server-side code to your project (e.g. for server-side rendering purposes and/or implementing an API endpoint). It will allow compiling and running your app using normal Create React App pipeline, using a single instance of Webpack, on the same HTTP port.

You can find more info by visiting [**React App SDK**](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-app).